# como definir un atributo en una clase de tipo json array en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Quisiera definir una clase que tenga un atributo que sea json array, ejemplo:

```
class dev:
 name:str
 skills: [{'phyton': 2}]
```

cómo podría definir skills en ese formato en una clase de phyton ? gracias

Comment: JSON es un formato de **intercambio**. Normalmente **generas** JSON cuando necesitas traspasarlo a otro sistema; no lo usas para procesos internos (mismo programa).

Comment: No existe en Python un objeto que represente a un json o uno de sus elementos, pero todos los objetos de un json tienen su equivalente en Python. Te recomiendo mirar la [tabla de equivalencias](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) que usa el modulo json en Python. En tu caso particular, pareciera que buscas crear una lista de diccionarios. Aun así, esto podría tratarse de un [problema xy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY)... Por que deseas lograr eso?

Comment: Ok, pero hay un ejemplo para definir este tipo de formato o como puedo manejarlo ya que debo crear un modelo para un api que esta este formato que recibe estos parámetros?

Comment: Podés usar el propio [modulo json](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/json.html) que te mencioné antes. Te permite crear una cadena de formato json a partir de objetos de Python y viseversa. Pero como dice Candid Moe, no lo uses para procesos internos. Primero trabajá con objetos de Python y luego creá el json.